# Azure B2C - Enable Self Service MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

with azure b2c, is there way to allow users to enable/self enroll MFA on their own profile ?

Comment: Can you share steps, what you tried to enable MFA in B2C?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with custom policies using the MFA starter pack.

- Change the Profile Edit page to add a checkbox to enable MFA
- User logs in and goes to the Profile page
- May select the MFA option
- Write the choice to an extension attribute
- User logs in
- Read the user attributes, including the extension attribute
- If the attribute is set, use a Precondition to invoke the MFA steps